# Redirect Rule needed

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I redirect http://example.com/sub/students/student_type/1 to 
http://example.com/sub/profile/1

sub is a subfolder and following is the htacsess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule . /sub/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

301 (Permanent) Redirect: Point an entire site to a different URL on a permanent basis. This is the most common type of redirect and is useful in most situations. In this example, we are redirecting to the "mt-example.com" domain:

->This allows you to redirect your entire website to any other domain

```
Redirect 301 / http://mt-example.com/
```

302 (Temporary) Redirect: Point an entire site to a different temporary URL. This is useful for SEO purposes when you have a temporary landing page and plan to switch back to your main landing page at a later date:

->This allows you to redirect your entire website to any other domain

```
Redirect 302 / http://mt-example.com/
```